# Accessing a TKinter widget from an other script

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I've looked a lot trying to find an answer to this.
I am new to this so please bear with me, I am making it as simple as possible.

I have two python scripts. GUI script with a button and an entry, and a script that has functions that display a message in the entry when the button is pressed. I was able to get the button in the GUI script to call the function in the other script by importing it and using the lambda function, and had it simply print a test message. Now I need to have this function change the value in the entry that is located in the GUI script.

GUI script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#  -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 5.0.3
#  in conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Apr 01, 2020 12:37:32 PM PDT  platform: Windows NT

import sys
import Test_1_Functions

try:
    import Tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = False
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = True

import Test_1_GUI_support

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = tk.Tk()
    top = Toplevel1 (root)
    Test_1_GUI_support.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_Toplevel1(rt, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another module.
       Correct form of call: 'create_Toplevel1(root, *args, **kwargs)' .'''
    global w, w_win, root
    #rt = root
    root = rt
    w = tk.Toplevel (root)
    top = Toplevel1 (w)
    Test_1_GUI_support.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_Toplevel1():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None

class Toplevel1:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        _bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        _compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        _ana2color = '#ececec' # Closest X11 color: 'gray92'

        top.geometry("1350x900+301+103")
        top.minsize(120, 1)
        top.maxsize(4924, 1901)
        top.resizable(1, 1)
        top.title("New Toplevel")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

        self.Button1 = tk.Button(top)
        self.Button1.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.344, height=94, width=197)
        self.Button1.configure(activebackground="#ececec")
        self.Button1.configure(activeforeground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Button1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightbackground="#d9d9d9")
        self.Button1.configure(highlightcolor="black")
        self.Button1.configure(pady="0")
        self.Button1.configure(text='''Press Me''')
        self.Button1.configure(command = lambda: Test_1_Functions.func())

        self.Entry1 = tk.Entry(top)
        self.Entry1.place(relx=0.356, rely=0.256,height=60, relwidth=0.173)
        self.Entry1.configure(background="white")
        self.Entry1.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.Entry1.configure(font="TkFixedFont")
        self.Entry1.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.Entry1.configure(insertbackground="black")
```

And the function script:

```
from Test_1_GUI import Toplevel1


def func():
    #print 'pressed'
    Toplevel1.Entry1.insert(0, 'MSG')
```

The error I get:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1547, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\DS Cloud\Python\Page-Tkinter\Test_1_OOP\Test_1_GUI.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    self.Button1.configure(command = lambda: Test_1_Functions.func())
  File "D:\DS Cloud\Python\Page-Tkinter\Test_1_OOP\Test_1_Functions.py", line 6, in func
    val = Toplevel1.editEntry()
TypeError: unbound method editEntry() must be called with Toplevel1 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I appreciate all the help

Jamil

Comment: You should pass the `Entry1` as an argument of `func()`.

Comment: `def funct(entry): entry.insert(0, 'MSG')` and later use it as `command=lambda: Test_1_Functions.func(self.Entry1)`

Comment: BTW: see [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - it is good rule to use `lower_case_names` for variables and `CamelCaseNames` only for classes. It helps to recognize class in code.

Comment: acw1668, thank you this did it!

Comment: furas, thank you for the document i have modified my code to stick to guidelines